# Convert DAL function into Stored Procedures in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, data-access-layer

Hi I have class for my Data Access Layer that contains a function called `GetCitiesByLocation` and it looks like this

```
public DataTable GetCitiesByLocation(long pStateID, string pKeyword)
{

    //create database object
    Database db = DBHelper.CreateDatabase();

    //create SELECT sql statement to be executed using string builder
    //add WHERE 1 = 1 at the end

    //add where [optional] statements
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pKeyword) == false)
    {
        //Create AND statement for ?Keyword
    }

    //add group by order by queries
    sql.Append(" GROUP BY c.city_id ");
    sql.Append(" ORDER BY city_name ");

    //Convert SQL String To DbCommand Object
    DbCommand comm = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sql.ToString());

    //Map Variables to mysql ?Parameters
    db.AddInParameter(comm, "?StateID", DbType.Int64, pStateID);
    db.AddInParameter(comm, "?Keyword", DbType.String, pKeyword);

    try
    {
        //execute sql statement and return results
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

See full version here: http://friendpaste.com/6ZGJHRNxQ9J57ntFD5XZi1

I would like to convert this to MYSQL Stored Procedure

Here is a failed attempt of my friend to convert it to MSSQL Stored Proc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Search]
@Keyword varchar(30)

AS

SELECT count(cc.course_id) as 'course_count',  c.*, con.* FROM city c
LEFT JOIN countries con on con.country_id = c.country_id
LEFT JOIN courses cc on cc.city_id = c.city_id
WHERE 1 = 1
AND CASE @Keyword WHEN (@Keyword <> NULL) THEN (AND c.state_name like @Keyword)  END
AND CASE @Keyword WHEN (pStateID > 0) THEN (AND c.state_id = @StateID AND c.country_id = 69 AND c.province_id = 0) END
AND CASE @Keyword WHEN (pProvinceID  > 0) THEN (AND c.province_id = @ProvinceID AND c.country_id = 52 AND c.state_id = 0) END
```

I have also transactional DAL which i want to convert to mysql stored proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on MySQL but it would seem that you're trying to execute a Stored Procedure the same way you would execute a Parameterized Query and that doesn't work.

I also would be very surprised if your MSSQL Proc compiled as I would expect that your proc would start with

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Search]
    @Keyword varchar(30),
    @StateID int = null,
    @ProvinceID int = null
```

Or in MySQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Search(Keyword varhar(30),
StateID int,
ProviceId int)
```

You would most like have to change your DAL in the following ways

1. Your existing DAL calls
   GetSqlStringCommand. You need to
   change that to GetSqlStringCommand to a GetStoredProcCommand.
2. your parameter names would have to
   change
3. the text woud be sp_search instead of "Select count(cc.course_id) as 'course_count..."

Comment: Hi, I know how to access a stored procedure and the parameters on the stored procedure example was purposely cut off just to represent a sample output I want. I want to convert my existing code behind DAL that has a series of if statements into a stored procedure.